# How to convert Datetimes into UTC based timing values to compare timings- C#

Tags: c#, datetime, utc, formatexception

I've string (variable is `fileDate`) with Date values in the following format:

> **2/12/2011 11:58 AM**

Now I want to convert this to a date and then to UTC time based as I've problems in comparing dates in different machines, so *I always want to convert all strings (which are getting compared) to Utc_date values.*

I tried this code below but it did not work as I'm not able to convert the above string to Datetime based (as it does not have seconds).

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(fileDate);
date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
fileDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

Above did not work showing FormatException. 
Can you pl help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, I'd suggest using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or `TryParseExact` - it's not clear to me whether your sample is meant to be December 2nd or February 12th. Specifying the format may well remove your `FormatException`.

The next problem is working out which time zone you want to convert it with - are you saying that 11:58 is a *local* time in some time zone, or it's *already* a UTC time?

- If it's a local time in the time zone of the code which is running this, you can use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` to do it as part of parsing.
- If it's already a universal time, use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`
- If it's a local time in a different time zone, you'll need to use [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) to perform the conversion.

Also, if it's a local time you'll need to consider two corner cases (assuming you're using a time zone which observes daylight saving time):

- A local time may be *skipped* due to DST transitions, when the clocks go forward. So if the clocks skip from 1am to 2am, then 1:30am doesn't exist at all.
- A local time may be *ambiguous* due to DST transitions, when the clocks go back. So if the clocks go back from 2am to 1am, then 1:30am occurs *twice* at different UTC times - which occurrence are you interested in?

You should decide how you want to handle these cases, and make sure they're covered in your unit tests.

Another option is to use my date and time library, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), which separates the concepts of "local date/time" and "date/time in a particular time zone" (and others) more explicitly.

Comment: Hi Jon, 
Yes. I'm facing that issue with Daylight Saving time. Basically, I converted both compared values to UTC time but still I'm facing issue with Daylight saving time. How Do i tackle this as it's blocking me?
Thanks for a detailed answer.

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT: It's hard to know what the problem is, as you haven't provided enough information. I asked various questions, and you haven't given answers to them yet. A short but complete example program demonstrating the problem would help.

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT: You still haven't explained which time zone you're really interested in (the code you've given will use the system local time zone, although you've not done the conversion in the simplest way - you can just use DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal). It's also not clear why you're converting *back* to a string, or what the other date is. You *claim* it's logically equal, but you haven't shown anything about that. A short but complete program would help to clarify some of this, but I suspect you're still not *really* sure what you need...

Comment: Hi Jon, pls refer to my another post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791712/how-to-take-care-of-dst-while-comparing-time-values-in-c-sharp] where I've included the requested data. Thanks

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT: Why did you create a new question instead of just editing this one?

Comment: Hi Jon.. Sorry for inconvenience. I felt that this post had too many questions/queries at one shot. Hence, I split it and posted a new one exclusively for comparison. This post has your answers which helped me in doing a parse from String to Date. Thanks for the Info.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `DateTime.ParseExact` to get the value into a proper DateTime instance, and then you can use `.ToUniversalTime()` to get the UTC time (this would be with respect to the difference of time as in your server machine)

Answer (score 0):

you can use :
`DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();`

i don't mean to say to you should use "DateTime.Now" but you get the point that as a part of the DateTime object you have a method to transform it to Universal time

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx