# How to take care of DST while comparing time values in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, comparison, utc, dst

I've two timings (as `String`) to be compared. These timing values are of Format as it could be understood from the code below:

***1st Timing value:***

```
String fileTime = new FileInfo(fileName).LastWriteTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

***2nd Timing value:*** (I take from list of Indian timings available in Database)

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(eachBinary.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"), TimeZoneInfo.Utc); 
eachBinary.Date = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt");
```

As you can see above, I want to compare the system file timings with those in DB records. 
Here, I see a potential problem of unequal timings even after conversion to UTC and then comparison of the Strings.

I know that the timings getting compared here for a file (say *file1*) are equal. But the program (or) application returns as they're unequal.

Is DST a problem here in my code? 
**If so, Can you pl help in taking care of DST in comparisons.**

**EDIT1:**

*1st Timing value* = 02/23/2012 09:08AM (it got converted from Pacific Zone, before conversion it was 02/23/2012 12:08 AM)

*2nd Timing value* = 02/23/2012 08:08AM (before conversion it was 02/23/2012 01:38PM)

Comment: Please show us your test case, i.e., show us (a) the file timestamps, (b) the actual values of `fileTime` and `eachFile.Date`.

Comment: Why do you want to compare strings when you can compare DateTime directly?

Comment: Probably one of your time variables has time zone information whereas the other one does not.

Comment: Heinzi - I've added additional information as requested.

Comment: @Alexel: my Database and my appln has fields already in Strings for Datelines. Also I display the values in "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt" format and hence I've strings. I would not want to change to DateTime now.

Comment: As requested before please show a short but *complete* program that demonstrates the problem. I agree with Alexei - why are you converting to a string at all?

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT: You should *absolutely* fix your schema and your code so that it uses the right data types. Keeping dates as strings will force you to perform conversions all over the place, confusing your code. If you plan to throw away your app soon, fine - but otherwise you should fix it, to avoid long-term problems. Don't take a shortcut - fix it properly. (It's even worse if those strings represent *local* times - in that situation you've also lost data due to ambiguity around DST transitions.)

Comment: Hi Jon, You're right. I wanna throw away(publish) my app soon and hence the need. Also, my DB or BackEnd has Dates in different format and hence I'm using Strings here. But I guess this is not related to the my problem in my post here. Thanks

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT: Thanks for adding the time value. Could you please add (a) *as well as* (b), i.e., for both values, show us the value *before the conversion* as well as *after the conversion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first conversion (`fileTime`) is the one returning the wrong value. I'm not in PST and my culture uses 24 hour clocks, so I had to simulate your first code example with the following code:

```
// 02/23/2012 12:08 AM (instead of reading LastWriteTime)
DateTime original = new DateTime(2012, 02, 23, 00, 08, 00);

// instead of ToUniversalTime(), which would use my local time zone
TimeZoneInfo pstzone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(original, pstzone); 

// instead of a plain ToString(), which would use my local culture
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
String display = utc.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", us);

// output: display = 02/23/2012 08:08 AM
```

So, it "works on my machine". I suggest that you try this on your machine. If it works as well, gradually replace parts (new DateTime -> LastWriteTime; ConvertTimeToUtc -> ToUniversalTime; etc.), until you arrive at your original one-line example. Note which step caused the conversion to fail -- now you know which part is responsible for returning the wrong result.